# Create a mixed type Pandas Dataframe using an numpy array of type "object"

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas Dataframe with mixed datatypes (float64 and strings), to use it in a sklearn Pipeline I need to convert it to a numpy array. In the end of the Pipeline I want to make a Dataframe again.

The problem is, when creating a numpy array with mixed types all data is converted to dtype "object". That way, when I create a new dataframe at the end all data is categorical.

Example:

**Dataframe with mixed data**

```
>>> dataframe = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],["a","b","c"]], columns = ["num", "cat"])

>>> dataframe.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   num     3 non-null      int64 
 1   cat     3 non-null      object
dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 176.0+ bytes
```

**To numpy array**

```
>>> array = dataframe.to_numpy()

array([[1, 'a'],
       [2, 'b'],
       [3, 'c']], dtype=object)
```

**Back to dataframe**

```
>>> new_df = pd.DataFrame(array, columns = ["num", "cat"])

>>> new_df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   num     3 non-null      object
 1   cat     3 non-null      object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 176.0+ bytes
```

Now the two columns are categorical.

Is there a way to make pandas recognize the true data types inside the numpy array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using pandas >= 1.0, there's [`convert_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html):

```
>>> new_df = pd.DataFrame(array, columns = ["num", "cat"]).convert_dtypes()
>>> new_df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   num     3 non-null      Int64 
 1   cat     3 non-null      string
dtypes: Int64(1), string(1)
memory usage: 179.0 bytes
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [**`infer_objects()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.infer_objects.html) as well:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(array, columns = ["num", "cat"]).infer_objects()
print(new_df,'\n\n',new_df.dtypes)
```

---

```
  num cat
0    1   a
1    2   b
2    3   c 

num     int64
cat    object
dtype: object
```